# Granularity of Paradigm Mixing

Tags: python, ruby, coding-style

When using a multi-paradigm language such as Python, C++, D, or Ruby, how much do you mix paradigms within a single application?  Within a single module?  Do you believe that mixing the functional, procedural and OO paradigms at a fine granularity leads to clearer, more concise code because you're using the right tool for every subproblem, or an inconsistent mess because you're doing similar things 3 different ways?

Answer (score 2):

Different paradigms mix in different ways.  For example, Using OOP doesn't eliminate the use of subroutines and procedural code from an outside library.  It merely moves the procedures around into a different place.

It is impossible to purely program with one paradigm.  You may think you have a single one in mind when you program, but that's your illusion.  Your resultant code will land along the borders and within the bounds of many paradigms.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I ever think about it like this.

Once you start "thinking in Ruby" the multi-paradigms just merge into ... well, Ruby.

Ruby is object-oriented, but I find that other things such as the functional aspect tend to mean that some of the "traditional" design patters present in OO languages are just simply not relevant. The iterator is a classic example ... iteration is something that is handled elegantly in Ruby and the heavy-weight OO iteration patterns no longer really apply. This seems to be true throughout the language.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing paradigms has an advantage of letting you express solutions in most natural and esy way.  Which is very good thing when it help keeping your program logic smaller.  For example, filtering a list by some criteria is several times simpler to express with functional solution compared to traditional loop.

On the other hand, to get benefit from mixing two or more paradigms programmer should be reasonably fluent with all of them.  So this is powerful tool that should be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

Different problems require different solutions, but it helps if you solve things the same way in the same layer. And varying to wildly will just confuse you and everyone else in the project.

For C++, I've found that statically typed OOP (use zope.interface in Python) work well for higher-level parts (connecting, updating, signaling, etc) and functional stuff solves many lower-level problems (parsing, nuts 'n bolts data processing, etc) more nicely.

And usually, a dynamically typed scripting system is good for selecting and configuring the specific app, game level, whatnot. This may be the language itself (i.e. Python)  or something else (an xml-script engine + necessary system for dynamic links in C++).